# Generating a Spring Boot WAR file with datasource properties predefined failing to deploy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

```
#TODO Change the datasource url along with the username and password
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=[my password here]
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


#TODO Change hibernate initialization-type before select executions of the applications

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true


spring.session.jdbc.table-name=spring_session
```

Above is my existing `application.properties` file. This is the file I have been using whilst writing my application on my development machine and use it to connect to my machine's MySQL server, without issue.

Unfortunately, when I want to change these `datasource` parameters so as to represent the database credentials on my Tomcat Server @DigitalOcean, it stops the WAR file from being built, as it attempts to connect to my machine's MySQL server with these new (and of course, incorrect) credentials.

What can I do in this situation? Is there a way of providing both sets of datasource parameters without forcing both of them to be accessed at once (to be more clear, allow the application to connect to whichever it 'can' at any point)?

Additionally, assuming this issue can be fixed, is localhost:8080 or localhost the correct url to attempt to connect to for the MySQL server when deploying on Tomcat at Digital Ocean. I understand this is a different question, but it's not as troubling as the previous one.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to set up spring profiles. This can be done using yaml `application.yml` file for the properties instead of the `application.properties` file. Please check out https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment and http://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml for more details.

Define the properties in your yml file like below

```
server:
    port: 9000
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
        username: root
        password: [your password]

---

spring:
    profiles: production
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://[IP address or hostname]:3306/db_example?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
        username: [required username]
        password: [required password]
server:
    port: 9002
```

Then when you build in your local environment, it'll try to connect with the default properties (where you need to specify local environment's creds/properties). When you need to deploy it with the creds on Digital Ocean, deploy your app with the `production` profile.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use JNDI for deployment on tomcat. If you want to support both, tomcat and standalone, I am using two different application.properties:

**application-standalone.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/my-application
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
```

For Deployment on **tomcat**:

**application-tomcat.properties**

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/my-application
```

**context.xml**

```
<Context>
    <ResourceLink auth="Container" name="jdbc/my-application" global="jdbc/my-application" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</Context>
```

**server.xml**

```
<GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          maxActive="20"
          maxIdle="0"
          maxWait="10000"
          name="jdbc/my-application"
          password="password"
          username="postgres"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/my-application"/>

</GlobalNamingResources>
```

**So you keep your secrets on the server.**